# List Generics and Casting

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have two classes: Media and Container.

I have two lists `List<Media>` and `List<Container>`

I'm passing these lists to another function (one at a time);

it can be one or another;

what's the proper way to check for the "template" type of the list so i can call an asssociated method depending on the list type?

or should i just try casting to the List<> and put Try/Catch blocks around it ?

```
    Object tagObj = mediaFlow1.BackButton.Tag;

    if (tagObj == Media)
       //do this
    else if (tagObj == Container)
        //do this
    else
        throw new Exception("Not a recognized type");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GetGenericArguments method of type Type, something like this:

object[] templates = myObject.GetType().GetGenericArguments();

Answer (score 11):

The proper thing to do is to have two overloads for this function, accepting each type:

```
public void MyMethod(List<Media> source)
{
  //do stuff with a Media List
}

public void MyMethod(List<Container> source)
{
  //do stuff with a Container List
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What David said.

But if this must go through the same function, the [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.) operator should help.  Also, this sounds more like you have an architectural flaw.  How is the Media class related to the Container class?  Is there some common interface used by both that they should implement?

Comment: yes, it should share the same function -- it's an eventhandler

Answer (score 0):

Well,  it depends on what your "//do this" method is... If it's a method that operates on a Media,  or a Container object, and does different things based on which it is,  then you should put that method in those classes...

Declare an interface named ICanDoThis

```
public interface ICanDoThis { void DoThis(); }
```

make sure that both Media and Container implement that interface

```
public class Media: ICanDoThis { // }
public class Container: ICanDoThis { // }
```

and then, in your client code "other function" you can

```
 public void OtherFunction(List<ICanDoThis> list)
 {
    foreach(ICanDoThis obj in list)
        obj.DoThis();
 }
```

And that's it... This code will call the appropriate implementation in either the Media Class or the Container class depending on what the concrete Type of the actual object is, without your having to write code to discriminate between them ...

Comment: This won't work until .Net 4.0 comes out.  Generic arguments don't yet know about inheritance.

Comment: I've done this before with a base class.. That's what the generic  where: interface  syntax is for... Are you saying that it doesn;t work for interface inheritance?

Comment: interface inheritance doesn't work:  List<Media> does not inherit from List<ICanDoThis>.  If OtherFunction was generic, you could restrict the accepted types to types that implement ICanDoThis and that would work.

Comment: public void OtherFunction<T>(List<T> list) where T : ICanDoThis